# Is there an way to fix this little problem with my background image on my responsive website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a new responsive website with navbar, text, background image, etc. Then a problem came up. There is under my footer a big white spot. Is there a way to change the code that there is also my background image? The Code is written in HTML, CSS and a few lines of JavaScript.

[My Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pM64r.jpg)

I have tried it with this code but it doesn't work:

```
body {
    font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: dimgrey;
}
```

My Code:
https://jsfiddle.net/q64g3ft7/2/

Answer (score 0):

[image]In your nav1-1.css file, add the following to the html,body,div,p,a,ul,li:

```
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
```

It will look like this:

```
    html,
    body,
    div,
    p,
    a,
    ul,
    li {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border: 0;
      font: inherit;
      font-size: 100%;
      vertical-align: baseline;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
}
```